# Power supply coupling of inductive resonant sensors

Tags: inductor, oscillator, inductance, resonance

I'm working on an array of sensors based on [Peltz Oscillators](https://www.testandmeasurementtips.com/basics-lc-oscillators-and-measuring-them/) connected to a micro to detect objects based on shifts in resonant frequency when a target object gets close to the inductor. In isolation, these work absolutely great for my application.

[image: Peltz]

- If I connect 2 of these to independent channels of my bench power
  supply, then all works as expected. Each sensor operates
  independently.
- If I tie the -ve of the independent supplies, everything still works great.
- If I power these from a single V+ (denoted with the gnd symbol in this schematic for some reason) then
  the resonance is completely coupled. Moving an object near one of the
  inductive sensors shifts the frequency of both circuits (definitely not what I want).

What modifications would be required to isolate each resonator so they can be operated from a single supply?

Comment: Power supply filtering, I would think. A capacitor across the supply for each one, and perhaps a ferrite bead in series with the supply. A common-mode choke is also commonly used for filtering power supplies, but I don't think that would help too much here. Just make sure there's a low-pass filter that blocks the oscillation frequency from reaching the supply.

Comment: Buzzing away about 1.5 Mhz, so simply strapping a cap cross the supply got me there. Facepalm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power supply filtering is about all you need for most problems like this. A capacitor across the supply for each sensor may be enough, or you may need to add a ferrite bead in series with the supply. Common-mode chokes are frequently recommended as well, but for this application it's unlikely that will do very much; I don't think this will produce much common-mode noise.

All you need, really, is a low-pass filter that prevents the operating frequency from getting to the power supply.

---

You also want to make sure you use shielded inductors for this; an unshielded inductor on one sensor could easily couple to its counterpart on another nearby sensor. At 1.5 MHz, you're not going to see much in the way of radiative coupling (an efficient radiator at 1.5 MHz would be something like 50 meters long, and I can't imagine there's anything near that size in your circuit), but near-field coupling is definitely possible.

Comment: Injection locking is inevitable. Just how close in frequency one oscillator can approach another's frequency before they lock - is a measure of your isolation success. At some point, coupling via common DC supply lines will give way to coupling by electromagnetic means. For radio frequencies, injection locking is possible thousands of kilometers between oscillators.